# How to come up with this JAVA gui application involving list component?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am learning Java on my own and I am taking on very small project by myself for fun, and I'm just stuck on this small part of the project.
So I have created a text file that contains a small list of toy names and prices, like:

Barbie, 12.95
Lego, 15.99
Hot Wheels, 5.00
Power Rangers, 6.49

And what I would like is my application to read the contents of the file and store the toy names in a list component. And then I want to be able to select a toy name from the list and add it
to a shopping cart that is a list component as well. I want to the application to have menu items and buttons to allow me to remove items from the shopping cart, clear the shopping cart of all
selections, and check out. When I check out, the application should calculate and display the subtotal of all the toy names in the shopping cart, the sales tax (which can just be 8 percent of
the subtotal), and the total.

Please help create this simple application example I've just made up, and I'm going to add and use this example to create a bigger application myself. I truly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Please break up the problem into small pieces and solve one piece at a time. Then if you have a problem post it here.

Comment: _"Please help create this simple application example I've just made up"_ - hlep yourself first by getting started on it.

Comment: since it's a project for fun, and not homework, I suggest you to put one information per line. It's easier to parse ;-)

Comment: Best place to start is with a plan, second best place to start is the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 1):

I've helped you to create all the GUI components involved which I believe to be the most tedious bit of your app unless if you have Netbeans, where you can easily create JFrame forms using their GUI editor. Also, instead of lists using Combo Boxes would be more appropriate for your selection of different toys, as it is dynamically resizable and won't be a problem for your GUI even if you have hundreds of different toys.

All you have to do now is to:

1. Create a BufferedReader to read in the text
2. Split the CSV using the String split() method, and parse the text into two separate arrays - one for the name of the toy, and one for its value
3. Update toysComboBox to display the input from the text file
4. Update addToCartButton to update shoppingCartTable to display the item name under the first column and the cost in the second column
5. Update addToCartButton to retabulate all costs in shoppingCartTable and then update subtotalValueLabel, salesTaxValueLabel and totalValueLabel
6. Update clearCartButton to set the entire shoppingCartTable to "", and also to set subtotalValueLabel, salesTaxValueLabel and totalValueLabel to $0.00
7. Update removeSelectedItem to remove the selected row in shoppingCartTable, and then push up all values below the deleted row to fill up the gap, after which it will retabulate all costs in shoppingCartTable and then update subtotalValueLabel, salesTaxValueLabel and totalValueLabel
8. Make something happen after you press checkOutButton - this is entirely up to you

Hope you learn something out of this and all the best for your project!

Code:

```
package test; // Rename with your package name

public class JavaProject extends javax.swing.JFrame { //Replace class name with yours


    public JavaProject() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

        toysComboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        addToyLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        addToCartButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        shoppingCartTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        shoppingCartLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        subtotalLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        subtotalValueLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        salesTaxLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        salesTaxValueLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        totalLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        totalValueLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        checkOutButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        removeSelectedButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        toyStoreLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        clearCartButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        splitLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        toysComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Barbie - $12.95", "Lego - $15.99", "Hot Wheels - $5.00", "Power Rangers - $6.49" }));
        toysComboBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                toysComboBoxActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        addToyLabel.setText("Add Toy:");

        addToCartButton.setText("Add to Cart");

        shoppingCartTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null},
                {null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Item", "Cost"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(shoppingCartTable);

        shoppingCartLabel.setText("Shopping Cart");

        subtotalLabel.setText("Subtotal:");

        subtotalValueLabel.setText("$0.00");

        salesTaxLabel.setText("Sales Tax:");

        salesTaxValueLabel.setText("$0.00");

        totalLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        totalLabel.setText("Total:");

        totalValueLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        totalValueLabel.setText("$0.00");

        checkOutButton.setText("Check Out");
        checkOutButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                checkOutButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        removeSelectedButton.setText("Remove Selected Item");

        toyStoreLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        toyStoreLabel.setText("Toy Store");

        clearCartButton.setText("Clear Cart");

        splitLabel.setText("_____________________");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(addToyLabel)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(toysComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 193, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(addToCartButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 107, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                                        .addComponent(toyStoreLabel))))
                            .addComponent(shoppingCartLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 362, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(clearCartButton)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(removeSelectedButton))
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(salesTaxLabel)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(salesTaxValueLabel)
                                        .addGap(257, 257, 257))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(subtotalLabel)
                                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                            .addComponent(subtotalValueLabel))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .addComponent(totalLabel)
                                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                            .addComponent(totalValueLabel))))))
                        .addContainerGap(12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(splitLabel)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(checkOutButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 154, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(checkOutButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(toyStoreLabel)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(addToyLabel)
                            .addComponent(toysComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(addToCartButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(shoppingCartLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 152, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(removeSelectedButton)
                            .addComponent(clearCartButton))
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(subtotalLabel)
                            .addComponent(subtotalValueLabel))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(salesTaxLabel)
                            .addComponent(salesTaxValueLabel))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(splitLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(totalLabel)
                            .addComponent(totalValueLabel))))
                .addContainerGap(41, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }                      

    private void toysComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                            

    private void checkOutButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JavaProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JavaProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JavaProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JavaProject.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JavaProject().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton addToCartButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel addToyLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton checkOutButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton clearCartButton;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton removeSelectedButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel salesTaxLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel salesTaxValueLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel shoppingCartLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTable shoppingCartTable;
    private javax.swing.JLabel splitLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel subtotalLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel subtotalValueLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel totalLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel totalValueLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel toyStoreLabel;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox toysComboBox;
}
```